# put data attribute on row add on DataTables 1.10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, datatables-1.10

I dynamically add new row on DataTables 1.10.2 using the `table.row.add()` method using this code:

```
table.row.add([
    '',
    name,
    target_l,
    details,
    panel.html()    
]).draw();
```

I produced this mark-up:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <th>1 .</th>
    <td class="sorting_1">ID Fee</td>
    <td>All students</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-null btn-xs" onclick="_remove(59, 'ID Fee')">
            <span class="fui-cross"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-null btn-xs" onclick="_edit(59, 'ID Fee', '', '')">
            <span class="icon-pencil"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I want to do is to **add a data-id** (and other data) **attribute to the newly added tr tag** (on or after row insert) and make it something like this:

```
<tr data-id="59" role="row" class="odd">
```

I've managed to get the index of the newly added row using the code and *it returns the last row index*:

```
var i = table.row.add([
    '',
    name,
    target_l,
    details,
    panel.html()    
]).index();
```

And also tried to perform the following to add the **data-id attribute** using *that* index:

```
var id = $("#department_id").val();
table.row(i).attr("data-id", id);
// table.row(i).data("id", id);
// I wanted to try this but there is also a method called data() already in
// DataTables so it will not work like in JQuery.
```

I'm new to DataTables and already scrolled its sourcecode, red the comments. Though not good at understanding its functions that begins with `_fn*()`. If there's any other way without relying on these `_fn*()` functions, thanks!

Comment: in your commented code, you say you wanted to do something like `table.row(i).data("id",id);` but cannot since DataTables has a function `data`. Have you tried wrapping `table.row(i)` in a jQuery function then calling jQuery's `data` on that?

Comment: `table.row(i)` is not a jquery object. You can't expect the data or attr functions to work with it. You'd need to wrap it first in the jQuery function before you can use the other functions `$(table.row(i)).data("id", id);`

Comment: Did you ever solved this, or it is still an open issue?

Comment: I havent yet solved this. :-(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [rows().nodes()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows%28%29.nodes%28%29) API function, see below:

```
var i = table.row.add([
    '',
    name,
    target_l,
    details,
    panel.html()    
]).index();

var id = $("#department_id").val();
table.rows(i).nodes().to$().attr("data-id", id);
```

Comment: Not sure why, but `.to$()` is not working on `.node()` for me. Had to use `$( table.row(i).node() )`

Comment: @FelipeLeão, thanks for you comment. It appears that `to$()` only works with `nodes()` and not `node()` which is kind of undocumented. Your workaround is fine.

Comment: .to$() turns the node into a jQuery element.